# Datalist populated dynamically in Angular with objects it's not returning selected object value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, autocomplete, html-datalist

I've a input text field with autocomplete based on what you're typing. The suggestions comes from a service that compares what are you tiping with an array of objects, specifically with the name atribute of taht objects.

Using the results of that comparision it returns an array of matching objects which I added to the dalist options so dinamically the autocomplete options changes as you type.

At this point fairly works, as you type the input field show suggestions but when you pick one I just get the name property from the option you picked up not the object (I don't know if I'm explainig this well).

The goal of all this is to use the option selected and two more dropdowns selection to perform a request to another service.

To track any change on the input text field or the dropdowns I have everything into a reactive form. So everytime the user change any value on the form I perfrom a request and update the results.

This is the controller side:

```
formGroup: FormGroup;
  cities: City [];

  selectedCity: City;

  cars;


  createForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      search: '',
      city: '',
      distance: '3000',
      sorting: 'price'
    });
  }

  async searchCities(search){
    console.log(search);
    console.log(search.search)
    this.cities = await this.citySearch.searchCities(search.search).pipe(first()).toPromise();
    if(search.city != ''){
      this.searchCars(search.city, search.distance, search.sorting)
    }
  }

  async searchCars(city, distance, sort){
    this.cars = await this.carSearch.getAvailableCars$(city, distance, sort).pipe(first()).toPromise(); 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formGroup = this.createForm();

   this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
     debounceTime(500),
     switchMap(data => this.searchCities(data))
   ).subscribe();

  }
```

This is the view, at this time and to keep working I use the autocomplete results to fill up a dropdown from where I pick the result so I can test the whole component. Aside of the datalist issue everything it's working properly. This is the view code:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <h2>City Search</h2>
  <input type="text" formControlName="search" list='cityList'/>

  <datalist id='cityList'>
    <option *ngFor='let city of cities' [ngValue]='city'>{{ city.name }}</option>
  </datalist>

  <select formControlName="city">
    <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]=city>
      {{ city.name }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <h2>Distance Search</h2>
  <select formControlName="distance">
    <option value="3000" selected>3 km</option>
    <option value="5000">5 km</option>
    <option value="7000">7 km</option>
  </select>

  <h2>Sorting</h2>
  <select formControlName="sorting">
    <option value="price">price</option>
    <option value="recommended" selected>recommended</option>
    <option value="distance">distance</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Awaiting a promise and binding to a component variable used in a template might be an issue? Not sure but doesn't look like a standard implementation. Any reason `this.cities` is set like that as opposed to using an observable? Suggest trying this `this.cities$ = this.citySearch.searchCities(search.search).pipe(first())`, then use the `| async` pipe in the template `let city of (cities$ | async)`,

Comment: This part of the code you are mentioning works fine. The issue is that when you pick one of the suggestions I don't get the full object on the controller just the name, which is the attribute I use on the autocomplete.

Comment: Ok -- next suggestion is to tweak the init of the `city` control in the FormGroup -- not sure if `[ngValue]` is going to know to map the full city object if you init it as a blank string. Maybe try initing as a FormGroup that maps the expected city props.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work neither

Comment: Not sure then, things look ok, maybe something with the double bind on both the select and the `datalist`. A total bandaid fix would be to add a `(change)` handler on the select and pass in the event value `<select (change)="onCitySelection($event.target.value)"...`, instead of using it within a form. Good luck!

Comment: I will try it and I'll keep u up to date bout this thanks for the help man